# Performance Penalty of Multiple VHosts in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a performance penalty to run many vhosts as opposed to many exchanges?  I have to support thousands of different clients, and I am trying to decide whether each client should receive its own vhost, or I should have one vhost and each client gets its own exchange.  Which is the better choice vis-a-vis performance and resource utilization?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Received an answer from RabbitMQ.  VHosts actually only exist as a security context so they have almost no overhead so there should be very little overhead in using many vhosts.